# How can I start recording on two iPhones at the same time?

Tags: iphone, ios, video

I have tried searching online with a broad variety of keywords, all of which turned up results for "shooting with both cameras on the same device".

Searching Video Production Stack Exchange also didn't help.

I am making a physics experiment and I will borrow iPhones for their high-quality graphics and built-in slow-motion. I will be recording two angles, so how can I get both iPhones to start filming at exactly the same time? Human error is not allowed so I can't get a helper and say "3, 2, 1, go!" so is there anything such as software, wires, or even a separate control from a third device that I can use?

Comment: Why not starting the videos one after the other and then editing them and cutting them to be the same length?

Comment: @Scientology same idea, it's human error with timing that's the problem

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is a solved problem for professionals by starting all recordings and using a [clapper board](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clapperboard). I'm not seeing any way to sync this with shortcuts or other mechanism, so you may need to control for this in post production.

A simple clap or other sharp visual / audio artifact is all that's needed to get the streams aligned and as long as the internal clocks aren't drifting much you hopefully don't need to control for clock skew on two iPhones.

[Most people won't detect a sync error of less than 22 ms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio-to-video_synchronization).

Depending on the margin of error you expect in your experimental measurement, you may need to control for the speed of sound or use a strobe or light flash for an accurate sync.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of this, all I needed was to make sure the two videos were exactly in sync. Creative and simple :)

Comment: I will be using slow-motion anyway so the sound will be even more precise to detect, and I could also use a helper with a flash of light like you said which is easier to see in frames than sound.

Comment: To add to this, Tom Scott did a video that talked about this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWYkoZKHLfg

Comment: The sound from a clap [professional board or just two hands;) is very easy to line up on - in fact video editing suites tend to have the facility to do it automatically these days [look up multi-cam shoot in your manual].

Comment: I love that OP was looking for a high-tech solution and the one that was presented was a tried-and-tested method that is over 100 years old. +1.

Comment: You are so very welcome @AyaNoaman - please let me know in a comment here how the experiment works out (or how it failed - those are useful, too for learning)

Comment: @bmike Alright, but it'll be a bit :)

Comment: Or sync in post with a short flash (eg, flick a light on). The clapper was designed to sync the video and audio tracks.

Comment: Somebody tell Martin of the Marble Machine that people can't detect 22ms out of sync! Never seen such obsession with "tight music".

Comment: In case it's not obvious, this (good!) solution will not be perfect.  Even if @AyaNoaman manages to pick the closest frames from the two videos, they will still be out of phase by up to half a frame.  That's only around 2ms at 240fps -- hopefully close enough for the purposes of this particular physics experiment!

Comment: @AC what do you mean by "out of phase by up to half a frame"?

Comment: @AC You can improve things by exporting at a higher frame rate. If you do frame-doubling, you would never need to be off by more than ¼ frame. If you do frame-quadrupeling you never need to be off by more than ⅛ frame. Granted, not having the shutters synced can be confusing, but if you are measuring "when did something happen" your answer will always be ±½ a frame anyway. On the other hand if you are measuring "where was something at a given time", you are loosing something by not syncing your shutters.

Comment: I'll be damned -- I never realized that's what those were for (clapperboards), if you can believe it. Seems obvious now that I think about it. +1 for the answer and for the enlightenment.

Comment: @justhalf  e.g. If both cameras capture one frame every 100ms and you start recording on camera A at t=0ms and on camera B at t=70ms, then they will be out of sync by 70ms.  The 2nd frame from camera A (taken at t=100ms) is actually closer to B's first frame (t=70ms), so you could improve the sync by offsetting the video to match but there will still be a 30ms mismatch between the two frames.  You might get lucky and start B at, say, t=301 in which case B's 1st frame (at t=301) is only 1ms away from A's 3rd (at t=300), but in the worst case it's off by 1/2 the frequency (50ms in this example).

Comment: @9072997 Great point about measuring a moment vs position!  I'd be careful with frame-doubling, though -- because those doubled frames are "lying" about the state of whatever they're photographing (at the reported time), you could end up with pairs of frames which claim to be totally in sync but show the world being in two different states at the same time.  Whether that's a problem depends on the experiment, I guess...

Comment: @AC ah, good point!

Answer (score 0):

Treating this as a an experimental setup problem rather than an iPhone problem (;-) )...depending on the angles you want and the volume you are filming, you may be able to use one or more mirrors to supply the additional point(s) of view, eliminating the second camera.
On the other hand, if I were using two cameras, I would include in both fields of view a way of making "clock ticks", such as an electric fan with one of the blades marked.That way, I could make up for any timing errors introduced by video compression in the two video streams.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The "clock ticks" tool is similar to @bmike's clapperboard/flash suggestion. The angle idea I tried and it didn't work, because one of the things I'm filming is an LCD monitor which is like one of those digital clocks that you can't really read from an angle. The mirror idea seems interesting, I'll see if it doesn't have the same problem